# Loader Image Not shows while Iframe Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a Iframe in page index.html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function iframeLoaded() {
        $('#loader1').show();
        var iFrameID = document.getElementById('idIframe');
        if (iFrameID) {
            iFrameID.height = "";
            iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
        $('#loader1').hide();
    }

</script>
```

the spinner image is shows when the page index.html loaded.

But i need to show it, when ever Iframe is loded.

Thnx.

Comment: use iframe.onload

Comment: Could you please explain the code?